# Interpreting a IV variable whose values have been changed

Tags: regression, interpretation, normalization

I'd just like to get advice on the following:

I've got a few independent variables which had values ranging from -2.5 to 2.5.

I used a formula to modify the values to be between the range [0, 1].

Now I have a dependent variable (% of manufacturing GDP)...how would I interpret the coefficients on the IVs.

What would a value of, for example, 0.4 on an IV mean?

Comment: The answer depends on what your formula is.  Perhaps you could disclose it?

Comment: Formula was the following - note 'x' here is the value between -2.5 and 2.5

$((x+2.5)/5)$